# Identify the pattern of this javascript function

Tags: javascript, closures

this is a brief pattern of a javascript function which I am not able to understand.
this is as seen here:
https://github.com/g13n/ua.js/blob/master/src/ua.js.

Note: This an edited version as per HugoT's response to my original question's answer.

```
function D(arg) {
   return function () { 
       return arg > 10; //arg is captured in this function's closure 
   }
};

object = {
    x: D(11),
    y: D(9),
    z: D(12)
};
```

SO how does this structure work?
I can see the return is an object.
But I cant put the things together.
Is this a closure pattern?
Can anyone explain the flow?

Comment: The code as quoted is a series of syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a closure pattern. Any arguments passed to D are captured in the closures of the function returned from D. However what you have written is not the same as in the code you linked.

This is the important part of the code you linked simplified

```
function D(arg) {
   return function () { 
       return arg > 10; //arg is captured in this function's closure 
   }
};

object = {
    x: D(11),
    y: D(9),
    z: D(12)
};
```

The values 11, 9 and 12 will be captured in the functions `object.x`, `object.y` and `object.z`.

Thus `object.x()` will return true while `object.y` will return false because `9 > 10` is false. `object.z()` will return true because `12 > 10`

Comment: Oh ok.. Your explanation with some dummy values helps. Thank You. and yes, I actually didnt consider the important part !

Comment: Great, glad to be of service.

Comment: *"This is the important part of the code you linked simplified"* The OP didn't "simplify" it, they rendered it non-sensical.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For the purpose of explaining what the code does it's certainly simpler than what codin linked to begin with. It might not make much sense to do something like it real code, but in the service of explaining the method it works well.

Comment: @HugoT: I disagree. Showing code that's nonsense rather than code that isn't nonsense is not useful in a question, and it breaks SO's rules in that it requires you to then go look at the link to figure out what the question is actually related to. I'm glad you were able to help the OP despite these flaws in the question (and upvoted the answer long ago :-) ).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did not know about that rule, do you suggest editing the answer be more consistent with the linked code?

Comment: @Hugo , I learnt an entirely new concept with your simple explanation. and  T.J.Crowder , pardon me for not asking the question properly as I myself am somewhat new to JS, else I wouldnt have asked the question if I could make sense of it.

Comment: @codin I am glad you did, if you could you should edit the original questions to be more clear on the code your asking about. This way the next person who comes around will understand this better.

Comment: @HugoT , Sure I will do that. Please dont mind if I use your answer as the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down `ua.js` to see what's going on. The outermost layer of the onion is an anonymous function:

```
var UA = (function (window, navigator) 
{ 
   /* anonymous function contents */  
}(window, navigator));
```

So UA is set to the return value of this anonymous function. So what does the anonymous function do? It sets a variable `ua`.

```
var ua = (window.navigator && navigator.userAgent) || "";
```

It defines a function `detect` which returns an anonymous function which tests the contents of ua against `pattern`.

```
function detect(pattern) {
    return function () {
        return (pattern).test(ua);
    };
}
```

Note that calling `detect(/something/)` does not return the value of `(/something/).test(ua)`. It simply returns a closure that will perform the test on demand.

Now we hit the return value of our outer anonymous function, which looks like this (I've chopped out the comments):

```
return { isChrome: detect(/webkit\W.*(chrome|chromium)\W/i),
         isFirefox: detect(/mozilla.*\Wfirefox\W/i),
         isGecko: detect(/mozilla(?!.*webkit).*\Wgecko\W/i),
         ...
         whoami: function () {
           return ua;
         } }
```

This is returning an instance of `Object` which contains a number of functions (`isChrome` etc), and those functions are the closures created by calls to `detect()`. This means that the execution of those `(pattern).test(ua)` checks are deferred until someone actually calls `UA.isChrome()` and so on.

You could imagine another approach where all the tests are performed up front, and UA becomes an Object containing a set of flags. This would have had the (probably fairly tiny) overhead of executing pattern matches that you as the developer are not interested in.